# How do I summarise month to date forecast for current month in Power Pivot?

Tags: powerpivot, datamodel

I have a table in a data model that has forecast figures for the next 3 months. What I want to do is to show what the forecast number for the current month to date is.

When I use the DATESMTD function like this:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(InternetSales_USD[SalesAmount_USD]),DATESMTD(DateTime[DateKey]))
```

I get the last month of my data summarised as a total. I assume that is because the DATESMTD function takes the last date in the column and that is 3 months away.

How do I make sure I get this current month MTD total rather then the end of the calendar? The formula should be clever enough to realise I am in May and want the May MTD not the August MTD.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to do this:

Forecast_Transaction_MTD:=CALCULATE(sum('ATO Online'[2017 Transaction Forecast]), DATESINPERIOD('ATO Online'[Current Year],TODAY(),-day(TODAY()),day))

the last -day(TODAY()) gets the day number for the current day and subtract it from today's date. So, today is the 25 May. the -day(TODAY())),day)) extracts the day (25) and subtracts it from the current date to get me to the 1 May.

The rest of the formula just adds the total for the dates.